Trouble with nft_info Account in Solana Anchor Test Code
I’m new to Solana development, and I’m having trouble writing test code for my program. Specifically, I can’t seem to properly initialize and use the nft_info account.
Here’s part of my Rust code:
#[account(mut)]
    pub nft_info: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

And here’s how I try to get the token account in my client-side code:
const nftMintAddress = new PublicKey(
      "2e9fSiMNFL1iv6tcSLZuMpDnqx2RVYkvRnLLhqgNYet5"
    );
    const nftTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
      nftMintAddress,
      user,
    );`
`await program.methods
      .test(value)
      .accounts({
        user: user,
        nftInfo: nftTokenAccount,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      })
      .rpc();

However, when I run this, I get the following error:
Error: AnchorError caused by account: nft_info. Error Code: AccountNotInitialized. Error Number: 3012. Error Message: The program expected this account to be already initialized.
I’m not sure how to fix this. It seems like my nft_info account isn’t properly initialized before it’s used. How can I ensure the token account is correctly initialized, or am I missing something in how I set it up?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I expected the nft_info account to be either:

Automatically created by the runtime or getAssociatedTokenAddressSync, or
Valid if it already exists.

It seems like I may need to explicitly create the token account first, but I’m not sure how to do that within the Anchor framework or if that’s the root cause of the issue.
Any advice on how to properly initialize or validate the token account would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
